# node-schedule Run every first monday of the month

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone please confirm that this is the right node-schedule rule that runs the code every first Monday of the month at 02:59AM.

```
var epr_update_rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
epr_update_rule.dayOfMonth = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
epr_update_rule.dayOfWeek = 1;
epr_update_rule.hour = 2;
epr_update_rule.minute = 59;
```

My idea is that it will try to run it on the first 7 days of the month but it will only succeed on a Monday and will therefore be run only ONCE in the first 7 days of the month, i.e. on Monday.

Can anyone please confirm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Object-literal** syntax, which is more easy and simple to undersdtand,

```
var job = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 02, minute: 59, dayOfWeek: 1, dayOfMonth: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}, function(){
  console.log('Your scheduleJob!');
});
```

[Here is the documentation for the same](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule#object-literal-syntax)

Comment: This schedule will be done on every monday in month.But @MihajloMilosavljevic wants first monday in a month

Comment: it mathces the first week days using `dayOfMonth`

Comment: So there is no need of mentioning months range like 0-11 in javascript week days must be mention with 0-7 i.e., 0 is sunday

Comment: he needs it to be done on every month, so month range is not required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sravan. Syed is right, I do want my job to be run ONLY on the first Monday of the month. My idea is that it will try to run it on the first 7 days of the month but it will only succeed on a Monday and will therefore be run only once in the first 7 days of the month, i.e. on Monday. I have seen the documentation I just need confirmation that this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: @Sravan, what if I want to send it on the second Monday of the month? Would this rule be okay: {hour: 02, minute: 59, dayOfWeek: 1, dayOfMonth: [8, 9,10,11,12,13,14]}